# How to map unwrapped JSON field to wrapped object with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-annotations

I have a JSON of structure

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "age": "..."
}
```

I have to map this JSON to following class object

```
Class Response {
  Person person;
}

Class Person {
 String name;
 String age;
}
```

Is there any Jackson annotation that helps me do this without changing the JSON structure or modifying the class structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `@JsonUnrapped` annotation over `Person person;` in your `Response` class. And by the way, classes in Java are defined by **class** not **Class**. Doesn't your code fails to compile? And you should add getters/setters to your classes if you haven't done already

**Response** class:

```
public class Response {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    Person person;

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

**Person** class:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

And here is a small test code to verify it:

```
    String json="{\n" +
            "  \"name\": \"Joe\",\n" +
            "  \"age\": \"30\"\n" +
            "}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    // convert JSON to Response
    final Response response = mapper.readValue(json, Response.class);
    System.out.println(response.getPerson().getName());
    System.out.println(response.getPerson().getAge());

    // convert Response to JSON string
    final String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, are you sure JSONUnwrapped always works for Deserialization ? The documentation doesnt mention it https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html

Comment: @AjaySabarish In my test code I show both serialization/deserialization (json->Response and Response->json), you can check on your own if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this a example to bind the json into the object
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_data_binding.htm

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, but in the example cited, JSON and Class structures are similar but how to map if the JSON is unwrapped ? Can you please apply it to my example ?